# Calling a form data from CakePHP to external PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, youtube

I need to upload a video to youtube from cakephp currentlly after upload the media file moved to "tmp' folder in cakephp `'app/webroot/upload/tmp'` youtube files are in `app/webroot/upload/youtube/upload.php`

**Cakephp output on form submission**

```
array(
    'postby_id' => 'user',
    'videoTitle' => 'my new video',
    'videoDescription'  => 'my description ',
    'videoTags' => hi,this,is,my,data,
    'date_posted' => '2016-05-26 10:21:16',
    'videoPath' => '11464258076.mp4'
)
```

**upload.php**

```
$client_id = 'MYID.apps.googleusercontent.com'; // Enter your Client ID here
$client_secret= 'MY_SECRET'; // Enter your Client Secret here
$APPNAME = "name";

$videoPath = "";
$videoTitle = "";
$videoDescription = "";
$videoTags = array("","","");
```

After upload youtube return video ID.

How can i pass form data from cake php form to this upload.php file? and that youtube video ID to cakephp?

Comment: Why not use CakePHP to post to Youtube? You could use a Lib or Component for that. You can however point the url attribute of your form to the upload.php so it will handle all incoming POST-data.

Comment: i'll try it with Component

Comment: Let us know if you have luck using a Component

Comment: how can i load 'require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';' in cake php component???

Comment: @gopu0000 you want to require the 'autoload.php' file in 'bootstrap.php'. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer.

Comment: @MBosman hi thanks its work

Answer (score 0):

solved by using a Component thanks to MBosman